# Maximum volume inscribed ellipsoid inside nonconvex polyhedron

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

In Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), an algorithm for finding the maximum volume inscribed ellipsoid inside a convex polyhedron is given (page 414, section 8.4.2).

I would like to find the maximum volume inscribed ellipsoid inside a **non**-convex polyhedron. Does anyone know an extension to this algorithm that could do this?

(The alternative would be to calculate an convex inner approximation of the nonconvex polyhedron and apply the original algorithm to that approximation.)

Comment: I don't think you are going to find an "extension" of the algorithms described there, no, since those algorithms do depend critically upon the convexity of the target region.

Comment: How exactly is the nonconvex polyhedron described? Do you have some sort of vertex-edge description?

Comment: It is described by a list of vertices.

Comment: If you know it's convex, that's sufficient, but if you don't, it's not---otherwise you don't know which vertices an "inner" vertex connects to.

Comment: Why not? If I have points A, B, C, D and connect them as A-B-C-D-A, then the result might be convex or nonconvex depending on the coordinates of the separate points.

Comment: Ah, OK, you're talking 2-D, sorry. So you do have edge connection info embedded in the ordering of the vertices.

Comment: I was talking about a 2D example, but I also want to do it in 3D. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Now consider a convex 2D polygon, and slice out a narrow, pie-shaped wedge to produce a non-convex polygon. Make the wedge long enough to nearly span the width of the polygon, so it's almost cut in half. So clearly, the inscribed ellipsoid you seek will have to be one one side of the wedge or the other. Now you really have no choice but to run two separate analyses, one for each side of the wedge. A convex algorithm, nor an adaptation thereof, won't be able to do this---it can't deal in disjoint scenarios like that.

Comment: Do note that maximum volume is easy when polytope representation is in facet description but generally hard in vertex form, and of course even harder if the polytope isn't convex. The oppositie holds for minimum volume.